# How to list non empty field names based on search criteria on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation, nested-object

we are encountering an issue on elasticsearch trying to display fields based on certain search criteria.

We have an index with a "payload" field which has multiple properties

[image: payload field and some of its properties]

What we are trying to do is to request the index to retrieve properties based on criteria.

For example, for all the logs where payload.codeClient=something, list all other payload properties ever set in messages matching that criteria.

We have tried some requests so far but none of them worked properly

```js
GET our_alias_name/_search
{ 
  "size": 100, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-6M/M" 
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "codeMessage",
            "query": "TRT*"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "payload.typeObjet.keyword": "paiement"
          } 
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "payload.*"
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_source": false
}
```

And what we get as an answer is obviously:

```js
{
  "took" : 304,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "azure_aks_container_logs",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ySzVVogB36_bMKME_Ll0",
        "_score" : null,
        "fields" : {
          "payload.applicationCible.keyword" : [
            "Kyriba"
          ],
          "payload.codeBranche" : [
            "MEF"
          ],
          "payload.typeObjet" : [
            "paiement"
          ],
          "payload.applicationSource.keyword" : [
            "SAGE MEF"
          ],
          "payload.typeObjet.keyword" : [
            "paiement"
          ],
          "payload.applicationSource" : [
            "SAGE MEF"
          ],
          "payload.codeBranche.keyword" : [
            "MEF"
          ],
          "payload.applicationCible" : [
            "Kyriba"
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          1685084047337346939
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index_name",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "uhbVVogBXEyG-ruo_HKV",
        "_score" : null,
        "fields" : {
          "payload.applicationCible.keyword" : [
            "Kyriba"
          ],
          "payload.codeBranche" : [
            "RHU"
          ],
          "payload.typeObjet" : [
            "paiement"
          ],
          "payload.applicationSource.keyword" : [
            "RHPI"
          ],
          "payload.typeObjet.keyword" : [
            "paiement"
          ]
          ...................................
```

but the test above does not show a field which has not been filled in query result, and what we want to get as an answer is not an array with messages content but an array with all field names that have ever been filled and respecting the criteria payload.typeObjet=paiement

We have looked at the possibility of using aggs but as said previously, what we want as an answer is an exhaustive list of ever filled (non empty) field names matching the search criteria

Comment: Could you please refrain from using screenshots but use the ```code snippet feature instead ?

Comment: @Paulo I have edited it to put my query and its answer in a code snippet. Thank you for the advice ;)